# Unable to complete HttpRequest - Error 500/403

Tags: java, android, python, django, http-post

I am trying to post a `HttpRequest` from my android application to python based backend abd encountering 500 request code error.At times, it gives 403

**App POST request**

```
private String Register(String email,String password) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String responseStr="";
        String URL=Constants.URL;
        System.out.println(URL);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

        try {
            // Add your data
            InetAddress ipAddress=null;
            try{
                ipAddress=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                System.out.println("IP of my Android := "+ipAddress.getHostAddress());
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception caught ="+e.getMessage());
            }
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ip", ipAddress.getHostAddress().toString()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            System.out.println(email+","+password+","+ipAddress.getHostAddress().toString()+","+URL);
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            System.out.println("after this"+responseCode);
            switch(responseCode) {
            case 200:
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if(entity != null) {
                    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    responseStr=responseBody;
                }
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"error", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Constants.AlertBox("Failed", "Unable to register. Please try again", Registration.this);
        } 
        return responseStr;
    }
```

**backend**

```
@csrf_exempt       
def registration(request):
    registration_dict = {}
    #if 1==1 :
    if request.POST:
        email=request.POST['email']
        password=request.POST['password']
        ip=request.POST['ip']
        location=request.POST['location']
        #email="admin@admin.com"
        #password='123456'
        #ip='203.192.223.115'
        user = auth.authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        if user is None:
            user = User(username=email, password=password, email=email)
            user = UserInfo.objects.get_or_create(user=user, email_id=email)
            registration_dict["status"]="1"
            registration_dict["message"]="Thank You for registering"
            now=datetime.now()
            UserHistory.objects.create(user=user,location=location,authentication=1,date=now)
        else:
            registration_dict["status"]="2"
            registration_dict["message"]="User already registered"


        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(registration_dict),content_type="application/json") 
    else:
        registration_dict["status"]="0"
        registration_dict["message"]="Unable to process the request"
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(registration_dict),content_type="application/json")
```

**LogCat Response**

```
07-30 18:17:10.459: I/System.out(9538):           <code>/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py</code> in <code>get_response</code>
07-30 18:17:10.459: I/System.out(9538):                 <ol start="104" class="pre-context" id="pre4328052856"><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                    for middleware_method in self._view_middleware:</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                        response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                        if response:</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                            break</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre></pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                if response is None:</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                    try:</pre></li></ol>
07-30 18:17:10.459: I/System.out(9538):               <ol start="111" class="context-line"><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)</pre> <span>...</span></li></ol>
07-30 18:17:10.459: I/System.out(9538):                 <ol start='112' class="post-context" id="post4328052856"><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                    except Exception, e:</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                        # If the view raised an exception, run it through exception</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                        # middleware, and if the exception middleware returns a</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                        # response, use that. Otherwise, reraise the exception.</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                        for middleware_method in self._exception_middleware:</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                            response = middleware_method(request, e)</pre></li></ol>
07-30 18:17:10.469: I/System.out(9538):                     <td>response</td>
07-30 18:17:10.529: I/System.out(9538): File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
07-30 18:17:10.529: I/System.out(9538):   111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
07-30 18:17:10.709: I/System.out(9538): this is login response 
07-30 18:17:10.749: I/System.out(9538):           <code>/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py</code> in <code>get_response</code>
07-30 18:17:10.749: I/System.out(9538):                 <ol start="104" class="pre-context" id="pre4328052856"><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                    for middleware_method in self._view_middleware:</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                        response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                        if response:</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                            break</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre></pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                if response is None:</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                    try:</pre></li></ol>
07-30 18:17:10.749: I/System.out(9538):               <ol start="111" class="context-line"><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)</pre> <span>...</span></li></ol>
07-30 18:17:10.749: I/System.out(9538):                 <ol start='112' class="post-context" id="post4328052856"><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                    except Exception, e:</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                        # If the view raised an exception, run it through exception</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                        # middleware, and if the exception middleware returns a</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                        # response, use that. Otherwise, reraise the exception.</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                        for middleware_method in self._exception_middleware:</pre></li><li onclick="toggle('pre4328052856', 'post4328052856')"><pre>                            response = middleware_method(request, e)</pre></li></ol>
07-30 18:17:10.749: I/System.out(9538):                     <td>response</td>
07-30 18:17:10.759: I/System.out(9538): File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
07-30 18:17:10.759: I/System.out(9538):   111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is several things you may check,

1. you can not invoke http request on ui thread, move it to another thread or async task.
2. it looks like you start your test server on local machine, you need to make sure it can be connected by your device, you need to start your django server, python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000